# How to make UISlider move smoothly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, uislider

I'm using AVPlayer and a UISlider as a scrubber for video playing.
Here are the codes:

```
__weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
avPlayerTimeObserver_ = [_avPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(1, 10)
                                        queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()
                                   usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {
                                       if (weakSelf.avPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay && weakSelf.avPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
                                           NSTimeInterval currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(_avPlayer.currentItem.currentTime);
                                           NSLog("currentTime: %@");
                                           [self.playerView.scrubber setValue:currentTime];

                                       }
}];
```

By checking the log in console, the value of slider was set many times within a second:

> ```
> 2014-07-28 10:41:07.044 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 19.609156
> 2014-07-28 10:41:07.145 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 19.709789
> 2014-07-28 10:41:07.245 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 19.809995
> 2014-07-28 10:41:07.345 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 19.909412
> 2014-07-28 10:41:07.445 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 20.009458
> 2014-07-28 10:41:07.545 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 20.109446
> 2014-07-28 10:41:07.644 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 20.209153
> 2014-07-28 10:41:07.744 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 20.309311
> 2014-07-28 10:41:07.844 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 20.409178
> 2014-07-28 10:41:07.944 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 20.509420
> 2014-07-28 10:41:08.045 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 20.610105
> 2014-07-28 10:41:08.144 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 20.709268
> 2014-07-28 10:41:08.245 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 20.809690
> 2014-07-28 10:41:08.345 TestAVPlayer[16733:90b] currentTime: 20.909868
> ```

But the thumb of slider moves step by step only every 1 second what ever I set the interval CMTimeMake(1, 10) or CMTimeMake(1, 30) even CMTimeMake(1, 100)

How to make it more smoonther ?

Comment: Try `[self.playerView.scrubber setValue:currentTime animated:YES];`